# document doesn't works for map display

Tags: angular, google-maps, ionic3, document

I am trying to use a traditional document to display a google map in my ionic app, but it doesn't work. If i use mean of viewChild, it works well. Can you tell me what is wrong in my code.

The code is:

app.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

...

import { Inject }  from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

...

@ViewChild('map') mapElement;
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document){}

...

initMap(lat, long){
  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom:0,
    scrollwheel: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
   };
   this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
   /* it works well if use mapElement */
   // this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

} 

/* here is some code triggering initMap()*/
```

ap.html

```
<ion-item *ngIf="select == 'map'>
    <ion-card  class="transparent-card" *ngFor="let subtrip of trips" >
      <div #map id="map" style="height:250px;"></div>
    </ion-card>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what the issue is, can you please clarify? Are you getting any errors? Could you provide a codesandbox or stackblitz so that we can reproduce this?